# WHERE com explode

Tags: php

Como faço um where com explode? tenho uma variavel com os valores "**5100**/**5101**/**5102**" e assim vai, queria listar as postagem com os ID dessa variavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode elaborar da seguinte maneira:

```
$var = "5100/5101/5102";
$var = str_replace("/", ",", $var);
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo IN ('$var')";
```

Usando o WHERE campo IN, você consegue retornar os id's desejados, de acordo com sua base de dados.

Comment: Modifiquei umas partes e funcionou, mas pode me tirar uma duvida? se tiver muitos ID, pode deixar a pagina pesada?